# How to create fixed/absolute position Tooltips on iPhones and iPads?

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, ipad, qtip

For some time now I've been happily using the [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) jQuery plugin. No complaints there.
However, on iPads and iPhones, the tooltips appears to be buggy.

Symptoms:

- Before resizing the touch screen everything seems to be working fine.
- After resizing etc. -- Inconsistent behavior. Some tooltips are misplaced; no real logic there.

Diagnosis:
It seems to me that Apple's touch-screens f**k-up the absolute and fixed positions for all jQuery calls.

How do I get by this? Anyone got into it? I googled the thing; couldn't find anything regarding this specific touch-screen issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Mobile Safari does not respect position: fixed; for starters.

Comment: I have the same problem. None knows the solution? Did you get it? I tried position:fixed, position:device-fixed.. And they don't work when the user zoom the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

actually tegeril is incorrect (partially) iOS 5 does [support](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5) fixed position iOS 4 does not. what version of iOS are you on? .